# Making NUnit use proxy settings or bypass proxy from TFS

Tags: .net, tfs, proxy, nunit, httpclient

We're running integration tests from our TFS server using NUnit. The tests need to access various HTTP APIs to do their job. All the calls to a certain address just gives us an error page (HTML) from the proxy server from Windows. (Internet options => Connections => LAN Settings says "Automaticlaly detect settings").

What I tried:

- Since the `VSTS_HTTP_PROXY` environment variable is mentioned around the internet, I tried setting `VSTS_NO_PROXY` (as an equivalent to the more generic `NO_PROXY` that works with other stuff). No luck.
- I tried setting our ignore-address in `.proxybypass` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/proxy?tabs=windows#specify-proxy-bypass-urls). No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set your proxy settings in the defaultProxy section of the App.config that's being used by the tests.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" bypassonlocal="True" />
            <bypasslist>
                <add address="192\.168\.1\.1" />
            </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

My guess is that all environment variables or `.proxybypass` files are used by the build agent internally for build steps - not by the code the agent executes. Which I guess makes sense since the build agent is just a process kicking off tests, more than a runtime environment.